# Making 3d render in adobe illustrator cc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

I just wanted some advice. Basically I got given a brief at work requesting 3d mock-ups to be made of a trade show display for a building construction retailer. I was asked to provide 3 different 'activation' options these being oversized jenga, a cash grab booth and a whackamole game.

The difficulty however is that I work at a commercial printer and we don't have the knowledge or 3d programmes to use as I feel something like this would be suited towards. I instead created the 3d models using adobe illustrator which is quite clunky as its a fairly new feature. I did make the below but was then asked to change the angle of everything which I found really hard to do with the 3d illustrator programme.

Just wanting to know/validate that this kind of job would be more suited to a 3d programme? As we had to go back and say that amending the angle of the 'render' was too difficult to change in illustrator. The time allocated was also 2 hours which wasn't I believe enough time for job required.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not having a "3D program" is not an excuse these days. Blender is free, and very light on specs for a computer, even if you have a 15-year-old computer you can run it or run an older version of it. It is a top of the line program.

Regarding the skills, you need to make a choice, do you want to learn or not, do you need to learn it or not really. If it is not your line of work, probably is better to decline. But if it can potentially be a line of work, make time to learn this.

Your project as it is, is very simple. You can also hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: Hi yes its of course something that can be learnt. The issue was that is was assumed as a 2 hour quick job and we don't have blender or any other 3d programme installed at work.

Comment: I think my question was more given the resources was adobe illustrator 3d tool the best to use. i found it quite fiddly and slow to edit it and was asked to change the angle of everything and found that really slow.

Comment: Yes. Learning Blender is a good investment. Once you have the basic setup changing a real camera position is super fast. It does not need to be "installed" you can even unzip it on a USB and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the learning curve of 3D applications isnt that big if you know how to use illustrator. I mean take something like Rhinoceros in which you can do mostly everything exactly like in illustrator if you wish.

The thing is though, you will quickly become greedy and then your learningcurve shoots through the roof.

In 2 hours with proper assets and budget a 3D app will kill anything you can do with illustrators tools. Better yet they often have superior editability too.

Comment: Ant to be honest not having a 3D app in your arsenal this day and age is a bit unforgivable for anything but really established players.

Comment: Well, thanks. Apparently, I am an established player :/

Comment: @Vincent its never too late ;)